# breaking a python script into multiple scripts

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I have a large python script with a lot of threads and functions running in the main script. Also, there are a lot of variables being shared among these different threads and functions. Now, I am looking forward to break this large script into smaller multiple scripts and a main() separate loop which will start all these threads, and also be able to share variables among all these multiple scripts.

So, my python script looks like:

```
import threading
import time
counter=0
counter1=0
flag=False
flag1=False
flag2=False
flag3= False


def function1():

    global flag
    if (flag==True):
       print "flag true"
    else:
       print "false"

def thread1():
    global flag
    global flag1
    while(1):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        flag1= True
        print "aa"
        flag= True
        function1()

def thread2():
        print '1'

def thread3():
        global flag1
        if (flag1==True):
           print '2'
        else:
           print '1'


def main():

      threadone=Threading.thread(target=thread1)
      threadtwo= Threading.thread(target=thread2)
      threadone.start()
      threadtwo.start()

main()
```

so, my code structure is as above, and it consists of 7-8 threads and many functions and many falgs and shared variables. Please suggest me how to break this code up into multiple scripts, and share flags and variables among them.

Comment: One comment - don't use globals to communicate between flags - use proper mutex semaphores.

Comment: This is a design question. Why do you want to separate them? Are there different components that can be decoupled here? Because breaking up a module that is conceptually a single unit will create high coupling between it's pieces, which is known to lead to headache.

Comment: I'm with @ReutSharabani, I couldn't see any real benefit in breaking the module since the functions are all somehow related.

Comment: Whether you break the code up into modules ore not, concurrent access to shared variables (and resources like `stdout`) between multiple threads needs to be tightly controlled and coordinated through some mechanism. This is often done using Lock, Semaphore, and Queue objects. In that sense your sample code is badly broken and you might want to fix that first.